# What was the original intent of US presidential power to pardon?

Tags: united-states

What is the original intention in granting the American president the power to pardon people for their crimes?

Comment: What do you mean "the" original intention?  The Constitution was written collectively by many people, and ratified collectively by many many more, all of whom may have had different ideas as to what the pardon power should be for.

Comment: Have you read https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/39066/how-are-presidential-pardons-supposed-to-be-used?rq=1 ?  If so, can you clarify what aspect of your question is not already answered there?

Comment: And also, as linked there, https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7674/why-is-the-us-president-allowed-to-grant-a-pardon.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge; my question is a duplicate of that one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are presidential pardons supposed to be used?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/39066/how-are-presidential-pardons-supposed-to-be-used)

Comment: I think this question should be closed on history as it is a duplicate (s.a.).

Answer (score 5):

### This was simply a continuation of the [royal prerogative of mercy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_prerogative_of_mercy)

This had been a power of the kings and queens of England (and successor realms) in use since at least 1617. Since 1688, England had been a constitutional monarchy with the monarch officially and legally subordinate to Parliament. However, a small number of residual powers remained with the monarch including the prerogative of mercy.

When the United States replaced the king with a President, they simply gave them the same power.

Comment: Henry VIII was also known to exercise this right, often in ordering a milder form of punishment. ([Thomas Culpeper, 1541](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Culpeper#Downfall_and_execution), where a simple beheading instead of being *hanged, drawn and quartered* was ordered.)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Henry was an absolute monarch (more or less) so he didn’t really have privileges- just whims.